# toggle information over images on click using css and js

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, overlay

How can i make on my portfolio images clickable to make appear information about project and re-clickable to hide this information on second click?
Will like to use simple js not jquery.

See website, but not it's working by holding the click and not toggle:
[enter link description here](https://www.zolfo.ch/test/)

Comment: could you provide a code sample of what you trying to do, so that we are able to help you with.

Comment: Add relevant HTML and JavaScript code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through your site a bit and this might be a possible solution to your problem.

Add the following script in your JS:

```
var imageElems = document.getElementsByClassName('image-box');

for (var i=0; i<imageElems.length; i++) {
    imageElems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.querySelector('.overlay').classList.toggle('show');
    });
 }
```

And add this in CSS:

```
.overlay.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

So basically what I have done here is I have added a click event on all your images with `className: image-box` which toggeles a class called `show` on click.

P.S. you should frame your question in a better way, providing code examples to your problem so that people in here can understand your problem better. The only reason why I tried helping you is because I see you are a graphic designer trying to do a bit of code, and it was encouraging enough! :)

Comment: You are adding `addEventListener` for every image, that is too much !!

Comment: Why is it too much? If you do a `$('.image-box')` in jQuery then its more or less the same thing. If he's wanting to do something with pure JS, then he needs to add an event listener on every image.

Comment: Yes, that's true, sorry my bad.

Comment: First of all thank you so much nashcheez. And yes, i have to post question in a better way, it's my first post here in stackoverflow. I try to make simple website and try to resolve myself some coding but it's not easy, i'm new to js.

Answer (score 2):

You can also accomplish desired effect without JS, pure CSS.

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

.pseudo-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pseudo-checkbox:checked + .description {
  display: initial;
}

.description {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <input type="checkbox" class="pseudo-checkbox" />
  <div class="description">
    Description
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrzej Ziółek but i will use the js + css way to do this. But thanks for your alternative way.

Comment: No problem, it is all about different approaches :). Thank you for your appreciation.